# cover and refinement (Godement Chapter 3 Q4)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Godement's definition of a cover of a set $X$ is a family $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$ (as opposed to the usual inclusion).

Keeping that in mind, here is the question:

> Given two covers of a set $X$, show there exists a refinement of each one.

For two covers $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(V_j)_{i\in J}$ of $X$, my idea is to take the union of all possible intersections between the elements of the two families (i.e. intersect all $U_i$'s with all the $V_j$'s then take the union) and check if it is a cover of $X$. I am writing this as $\bigcup_\limits{i\in I}\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}\big(U_i\bigcap U_j\big)$.

So I have two questions:

1) Is what I have written indeed the union of all intersections between elements of the two covers?

2) Is the the union of all intersections a cover of $X$? + A hint on how to show why / why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The notation is fine, a condensed one: $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I, j\in J}\big(U_i\bigcap V_j\big)$

2) Let $x\in \bigcup_{j\in J}\big(U_1\bigcap V_j\big)$, this is equivalent to saying there exists $j\in J$ such that $x\in \big(U_1\bigcap V_j\big)$, i.e. $x\in U_1$ and there is $j\in J$ such that $x\in V_j$ which is the same as saying $x\in U_1$ and $x\in \bigcup_{j\in J}V_j$. Now this is equivalent to $x\in U_1\bigcap \big(\bigcup_{j\in J}V_j\big)$. Do the same for each $U_i$ and we get $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I, j\in J}\big(U_i\bigcap V_j\big) = \big(\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\big)\bigcap \big(\bigcup_{j\in J}V_j\big)$. And since each family is a cover of $X$, this intersection is also cover of $X$.